# Can this choice-collection principle prove the well ordering theorem without power set axiom?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, axioms

**Choice Collection:** if $\phi(x,y)$ is a formula in which "$B$" doesn't occur free, and "$x,y$" are among its free variables; then: $$\forall A \exists B \forall x \in A \, (\exists y \, \phi(x,y) \implies \exists! y : \langle x, y \rangle \in B \land \phi(x,y))$$

$\langle ,\rangle$ stands for ordered pair.

We shall denote this axiom by "$\sf C.Col$".

So $\sf ZFC$ can be written as $\sf Z + C.Col$

This axiom would prove both $\sf AC$ and [Collection\Boundedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement#Collection) schema over the rest of axioms of $\sf Z$. It is a theorem of $\sf ZFC$ and $\sf NBG$ \ $\sf MK$.

> Can $\sf Z+ C.Col-Power$ prove that every set can be well ordered?